# Creating objects according to the number of variables passed to the function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dictionary, variables

I would like to summarise what I do in this script by creating a function that takes into account the number of parameters I enter.

```
parameters = {
    "x1" : list(np.linspace(start=10, stop=25, num=10)),
    "x2" : list(np.linspace(start=23.5, stop=75, num=10)),
    "x3" : list(np.linspace(start=20, stop=200, num=10)),
    "x4" : list(np.linspace(start=2.4, stop=34.7, num=10))
}

a1 = random.choice(parameters['x1'])
a2 = random.choice(parameters['x2'])
a3 = random.choice(parameters['x3'])
a4 = random.choice(parameters['x4'])
b1 = random.choice(parameters['x1'])
b2 = random.choice(parameters['x2'])
b3 = random.choice(parameters['x3'])
b4 = random.choice(parameters['x4'])

iteration1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': [a1,b1,a1,a1,a1],
    'x2': [a2,a2,b2,a2,a2],
    'x3': [a3,a3,a3,b3,a3],
    'x4': [a4,a4,a4,a4,b4],
})
```

So I would like to get a generic function that depending on the number of parameters that are in the dict generates me that final matrix.
I'm trying this kind of approach but then I don't know how to proceed.

```
def show_user_info(**parameters):
    # data is a dict
    for par, range_ in parameters.items():
        **par = random.choice(parameters[par])
```

Sorry if this question may seem trivial to some but I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
def show_user_info(N, **parameters):
    data = [np.random.choice(l, len(parameters))
               for k, l in parameters.items() 
               for i in range(N)]
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=parameters.keys())

# show_user_info(2, x1=..., x2=..., x3=..., x4=..., x5=...)
df = show_user_info(2, **parameters)
print(df)

# Output
           x1          x2          x3          x4
0   23.333333   23.333333   15.000000   11.666667
1   10.000000   10.000000   16.666667   11.666667
2   69.277778   69.277778   29.222222   29.222222
3   63.555556   46.388889   34.944444   69.277778
4  100.000000   80.000000   40.000000  180.000000
5   60.000000  120.000000  160.000000  140.000000
6   31.111111   27.522222    2.400000   20.344444
7    2.400000   27.522222   13.166667   34.700000
```

Comment: The matrix I obtain in this way is different from the one I have described. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SimonePanico. In your matrix, you have 5 rows. Why five? How do you control this parameter?

Comment: Perhaps the way I have written can be confusing. If you notice, the matrix I want to obtain is structured in a particular way. Once I have found the 8 values a1...b4 I insert them into the matrix in that exact order.